# C# Regex Compatibility Issue (.NET 3.5 vs .Net 2.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation, email-validation

I have the following regex expression on a dev machine that is running .NET 3.5 and it works as designed.  However when it is deployed to our test environment (which is running .NET 2.0) it doesn't work right and always seems to return false.  Does anyone know what the culprit may be?  Thanks

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

protected void emailContactCheck(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
  string[] allContacts = this.Contacts.InnerText.ToString().Split(";,".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  Regex rx = new Regex(@"^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\""]+"
                    + @"(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\""]+)*)|(\"".+\""))@"
                    + @"((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"
                    + @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+"
                    + @"[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  foreach (String contact in allContacts)
  {
    if (!rx.IsMatch(contact.Trim()))
    {
      args.IsValid = false;
      return;
    }
  }
  args.IsValid = true;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the test and development environments have the same data?  I don't know what this.Contacts contains, and there's no way to be absolutely sure they're equivalent.

Comment: Find some sample data that is failing and we should be able to help.

Comment: You're using `\""` to escape the quotation marks when you only need `""`.  Getting rid of the backslash probably won't fix your problem, but it will let SO's syntax highlighting work correctly, making it easier for us to read the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html), there are no differences in regex support between .NET 2.0 and 3.x, so the problem is probably not with the regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set the .Net version of your dev machine to .Net 2.0 too. Can be done on the project build properties. You should always use the same version as on your test/production system.

Then you can try to check whether you can reproduce the problem also on your dev machine running .Net 2.0.